# clients.openWindow not opening standalone app

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, service-worker

I want to open a standalone web app added to home screen from a received push notification. Almost everything is working fine, except that when I click the notification when the stand-alone app or a browser is not open, it gives me a random list of other irrelevant apps [screenshot attached].

[image: Push Notification Received] > [image: When I click, gives irrelevant list of apps]

Here is my code on Service Worker where I try to open the app.

```js
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event){
     var data = event.notification.data;
     event.notification.close();
     event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
      type: 'window'
     })
     .then(function(clientList) {
      for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
       var client = clientList[i];
       if (client.url.split('#')[0] == 'https://account.info.lk/' && 'focus' in client){
        client.navigate(data.url);
        return client.focus();
       }
      }
      if (clients.openWindow)
       return clients.openWindow(data.url);
     }));
    });
```

Please help me get the standalone app (or at least on a browser window open when a push notification is clicked.

Comment: Not a Chrome Apps question.

Comment: You may want to check this [thread](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-push-messaging/issues/71) on how to launch app from homescreen if clicked upon a push notification. It stated that recreating the home screen icon shouldn't be necessary unless you created your homescreen shortcut using a fairly old version of Chrome. There is a requirement that you have launched your app recently (<10 days) for this to work. Check this [reported issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541711) for more information.

Comment: What's `event.notification.data.url` set to when you see this happening?